# Waiting until method is finished

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have an array `public trackedElements: TrackingEvent[];` in which I write data:

```
this.trackedElementService.trackingEventsGetTrackingEventsbyElementIdFromtimestampTotimestampElementIdGet(this.fromDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), this.toDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), this.trackedElement.elementId.toString()).subscribe((data: TrackingEvent[]) => {
   this.trackedElements = data;
});
```

I call this method the moment the component is initialized, but this.trackedElements doesn't have all the data when the next method is already called in which I want to use the data.

My goal is to figure out how to stop the next method to be called until this.trackedElements is filled completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try calling the next method after variable has data

```
this.trackedElementService.trackingEventsGetTrackingEventsbyElementIdFromtimestampTotimestampElementIdGet(this.fromDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), this.toDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), this.trackedElement.elementId.toString()).subscribe((data: TrackingEvent[]) => {
   this.trackedElements = data;
// please call next method here like, this.nextMethod()
});
```

Comment: Use what @Prateek wrote and/or consider various lifecycle hooks that Angukar provides, to be sure you're firing up your code when data is ready.

Comment: I was just about to explain my problem further because it still wasn't working but somehow it is working just fine now. So thank you!